# SWT Browser -- get selected text

Tags: java, swt

I am using a Browser view in my application and i need to get the text selected by user. I tried creating mouse event but nothing is working. I am using following link to create the browser:

http://180.179.103.253/q3/twapp/process.php?mdl=onetimeurl&id=1061&deviceid=9d2aefc2-a386-4afc-b307-44f41ec8311d&test=1

I also checked in documentation, there is no method like [`getSelectionText()`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html) in SWT browser.

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this by executing java script function in the browser from your View.Write a java script to get the selection the text and execute it in the browser.
Look at the Browser API:

```
browser.execute(script);
browser.evaluate(script);
```

Look at `BrowserFunction` interface for java-javascript call back mechanism